# How to build Object for list items in json request

Tags: php, json, object

I'm writing class:

```
class User {
    public function info() {
        $this->name = "John";
        $this->surname = "Smith";
    }
}
```

In json query I've receive:

```
[{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}]
```

That's right. But I want to write another Class with list users, when json receive me something like this:

```
[{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}, {"name":"Kate","surname":"Philips"}, ...]
```

It's posiible? How? Please help me because I'm beginner programmer.

Comment: Do you have a method in that *User* class from where you're getting this encoded JSON string?

Comment: <?php

class TestUserList{
    public $var = array();
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $this->var = $array;
        }
    }
}

And:

$vars[] = array('name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Smith');
$vars[] = array('name' => 'Kate', 'surname' => 'Philips');
$users = new TestUserList($vars);
echo json_encode(users);

Comment: You're almost there. Just change `echo json_encode(users);` to `echo json_encode($users->var);` and you'll get your desired result.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. It's work! :)